# What does "above" mean exactly?

Tags: meaning

> The hill above the river dominated the landscape, which was
>   predominantly flat and barren.

I am wondering if above means "next to and at a higher position relative to". Above can mean a lot of things, but when talking about geographical landmarks and features, does above pretty much always mean "next to and at a higher position relative to"?

Comment: I actually wrote that, because I couldn't find an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the river flows *underneath or through* the hill. In which case, the hill is literally *only* above the river and not next to it (in a horizontal sense) at all.

The river could even be *subterranean*—meaning it's some distance away from the hill, even vertically.

But while those are *possible* interpretations of the sentence, and not *always* wrong, it's unlikely either is the intended meaning. Far more often than not, you'd be correct in assuming that the river is *beside* and *close to* the hill.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think 'above' does imply proximity. You cannot say "The hill was above the river, and a hundred miles away from it".

"Next to and at a higher position relative to" seems like a perfect definition of what it means to me.